# How to get exact count of documents that matches a Solr query

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, nosql, lucene, solrj

I am a newbie in Solr and I want to migrate from Elasticsearch to Solr. I want to know how to get the exact count of documents that matches Solr query. I used this in Elasticsearch :

```
AggregationBuilders.count("count").field("someField")
```

is there sth like count aggregation in solr without considering pagination parameters? or if I don't use some parameters in search like *timeAllowed* or *minExactCount*, Is the *numFound* result accurate? or *numFoundExact* can be true in some cases and affects on *numCount* result.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you explicitly tells Solr that making optimizations is OK (i.e. parameters such as `timeAllowed` or `minExactCount`), `numFound` should be exact.

There is also approximations available in other functions for speeding up queries, such as using hyper log log approximations.

Comment: can I use this query and facet? {
  "query": " *:* -_nest_path_:*",
  "facet": {
    "totalCount": "countvals(id)"
  }
}

Comment: @sabasafavi Please ask a new question with the proper details attached; I'm not sure what you're asking. Try first, then ask your question with details about what you tried and what failed. I'm not familiar with `countvals` and `nest_path`.